# Migrating to 64-bit - how to fix ddl dependencies? [Visual Studio 2008]

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, dependencies

I am currently developing a software which is based on the Visual Studio 32-bit (`x86`) platform. However, I feel that a move to 64-bit (`x64`) would offer substantive advantage in that we can use 4GB of memory as opposed to 2GB limit on the 32-bit. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

As a first step - I installed the `x64` compiler and tools for Visual Studio using the installation disk. When I compile it now and run the new executable created using `x64` platform, I get the `0xc000007b error`. On googling this I found that a potential solution would be to trace back the dependencies. So I used the `dependencywalker`. Here is the output:

[image: dependencywalker Output]

As you would notice - all the dlls show the CPU as `x86`. Also, all the dlls are always accessed from my `system32` folder instead of `syswow64` folder. What is happening here? Can I get this fixed by pointing it to the x64 dlls - how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have **no need** to specify "dll folder". You need properly set up your project, for example target machine type in linker properties.